# How to change the jquery ui accordion default icon to plus icon globally

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using `Jquery UI Accordion` in my rails project. The `accordion` using the `arrow images` as a default one. I need to change that arrow icon to `Plus icon` as default. Where shall i edit to make the `Plus and minus icon` to default to change all over the sites. I am using the accordion in lot of pages?

I seen more related this question in other posts. In my case is in ruby-on-rails project. I want to change the icon globally to take the effect all over the project.

I added the following line to each page to make it working of what i want. I feel its not the DRY Principle. I need to set like this globally to work all the pages in the whole site.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content"
    });
    /* Change the accordion image to Plus and minus */
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", 
        { 'header': 'ui-icon-plus', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-minus' });
  });
</script>
```

Any suggestions and helps would be more appreciated...

Comment: Please provide the reason for the downvote Gentlemen ....

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI has extensive documentation for their widgets. Go check out the docs for the Accordion (specifically for changing the icon) [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-icons).

Further reading on the CSS framework mentioned in those docs is [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API#Icons).

For instance, if you go to jQuery UI's [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), you can look at the big grid of icons, find the one you like, hover over it to see the class name, and then use that name in the documentation from my first link to configure your Accordion menu to use the icon you chose. If you look at the documentation in the first link, the example actually uses the plus and minus icons for when the content is collapsed/expanded respectively.

Comment: yeah, But I can't find to change the default icon ... I knew that we can use different image rather than traingle image.

Comment: @Sri Refer to the additional info I put in my answer. All the information you need is sitting in those links, particularly the first and third links.

Comment: @Sri I think I may have misunderstood exactly what you want. Do you want a central location to change what icon you use *in your Ruby code*? Because there is no "default setting" for icons on a global scale for jQuery UI Accordions unless you directly edit the jQuery UI source code (which is bad practice). Each Accordion will have to be individually changed. You could probably best emulate a "global setting" by managing your Accordion options and creation code with Ruby. A quicker, dirtier, less-maintainable solution would be a find-replace through your entire codebase for the icon setting.

Comment: Yes.... That's the thing i want... I updated the question.. Please have a look again.